# Running shiny app through nginx and letsencrypt ssl using docker

Tags: docker, nginx, shiny, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

I would like to run my app (myapp) on my domain ([www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com)) through nginx reverse proxy and letsencrypt ssl using docker. Everything looks right, but I can't see my app running on my domain.

If I run my docker app without using the reverse proxy and SSL, I can see my app running on my domain.

I have done the following:

1. Running the proxy

```
$ cd
$ mkdir certs

$ docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
    --name nginx-proxy \
    -v $HOME/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro \
    -v /etc/nginx/vhost.d \
    -v /usr/share/nginx/html \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro \
    --label com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true \
    jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

2. Running the Let's Encrypt companion container:

```
$ docker run -d \
    --name nginx-letsencrypt \
    --volumes-from nginx-proxy \
    -v $HOME/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
```

3. My app dockerfile:

```
# get shiny server and R from the rocker project
FROM rocker/shiny:4.0.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-dev \
    libsodium-dev

# install R packages required 
# Change the packages list to suit your needs
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'shinythemes', 'dygraphs', 'shinyWidgets', 'manipulateWidget', 'DT', 'zoo', 'shinyjs','emayili', 'wordcloud2', 'rmarkdown', 'xts', 'shinyauthr', 'curl', 'jsonlite', 'httr'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

# copy the app directory into the image
WORKDIR /srv/shiny-server/myapp/app
COPY app .

# run app
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/srv/shiny-server/myapp/app',  host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080)"]
```

4. Finally, I have built and run my docker app:

```
$ cd /srv/shiny-server/myapp
$ sudo docker build -t myapp .

$ docker run -d \
    --name mysite \
    -e 'LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@myapp.com' \
    -e 'LETSENCRYPT_HOST=myapp.com' \
    -e 'VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp.com' myapp
```

Unfortunately, when I visit my domain, I see a page with the message:

http://myapp.com -> 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.21.6

https://myapp.com -> 500 Internal Server Error nginx/1.21.6

I can't see my app running.

If I run the following, after running the nginx-proxy and nginx-letsencrypt containers,

```
$ docker run -d \
    --name nginx \
    -e 'LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@myapp.com' \
    -e 'LETSENCRYPT_HOST=myapp.com' \
    -e 'VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp.com' nginx
```

I can see:

http://myapp.com -> Welcome to nginx!

https://myapp.com -> 500 Internal Server Error nginx/1.21.6

If I just run the nginx-proxy and the nginx-letsencrypt containers, I get the following:

http://myapp.com -> 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable  nginx

https://myapp.com -> 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable  nginx

Comment: Please, share you vhost file also.

Comment: I have edited my question. I can't find the vhost file

Comment: Right. To nginx works as reverse proxy you will need a vhost config. Error 500 on https access could be some failure with certificates. 503 error usually means that a reverse proxy is working but no reaching application.

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, I suppose the important errors here are 502 and 500. I get these errors when I run my docker app behind the proxy. Could you help me with this issue? Do I have the right ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps here are multiple problems.

1. **Port**
   In your Dockerfile, you wrote `EXPOSE 80` and after that you start shiny with port `8080`.
   You should write `EXPOSE 8080` instead. When you start your app-container, then you might must specify [VIRTUAL_PORT](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy).
2. **SSL Certs**
   I think, that nginx is not happy about the certs. A `500` always means, that there is a problem on server-side.
   Have a look in the logs of nginx (`docker logs nginx-proxy`).
   In general, I recommend to avoid dockerized certs (they are pretty complex and often cause erros). Have look at point 4 of my other answer: [Can't enable ssl by docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112313/cant-enable-ssl-by-docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/61201890#61201890)
3. **Unused mounts**
   Maybe I am wrong, but I think that some volumes are not necessary. Like `-v /etc/nginx/vhost.d`.

Good luck.

Comment: Excellent! It works! I have simply written EXPOSE 8080 in my dockerfile and I have added -e VIRTUAL_PORT=8080 to run my app. I guess EXPOSE is equal to port (in Shiny). There was also an error with my IPv6 and Let's Encrypt, so I deleted my AAAA records. I have also tried to address this issue with docker compose and two apps but it doesn't work. I would appreciate if you could answer my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73359253/problem-using-jwilder-nginx-proxy-for-multiple-domains