# Problem using jwilder/nginx-proxy for multiple domains

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two apps (app1 and app2) and I would like to run them on my domains (domain1 and domain2). I use docker containers to do this and a docker reverse proxy. If I run each docker app independently, they work well. When I execute docker-compose up -d and I visit my domains, I can see the following message: Welcome to nginx!. I can't see my apps running.

My docker-compose.yml is the following:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
 proxy:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
  container_name: proxy
  labels:
   com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
  ports:
   - "80:80"
   - "443:443"
  volumes:
   - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
   - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
   - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock

 letsencrypt:
  image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
  container_name: letsencrypt
  environment:
   - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=proxy
  volumes:
   - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
   - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
   - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

 app1:
  image: app1_image
  container_name: myapp1
  expose:
   - "9090"
  environment:
   - VIRTUAL_PORT=9090
   - VIRTUAL_HOST=domain1.com www.domain1.com
   - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=domain1.com www.domain1.com
   - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@domain1.es
  volumes:
   - /srv/shiny-server/app1/app/data:/srv/shiny-server/app1/app/data

 app2:
  image: app2_image
  container_name: myapp2
  expose:
   - "8080"
  environment:
   - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
   - VIRTUAL_HOST=domain2.com www.domain2.com
   - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=domain2.com www.domain2.com
   - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@domain2.es
  volumes:
   - /srv/shiny-server/app2/app/data:/srv/shiny-server/app2/app/data

volumes:
 certs:
 html:
 vhostd:
```

If I don't use the detach mode and I execute the docker containers, I get the following error:

```
$ docker-compose up

myapp1   | Listening on http://0.0.0.0:9090
myapp2   | 
myapp2   | Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080
...
proxy | nginx.1 | myserverIP - - [16/Aug/2022:17:33:01 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://www.domain1.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0" "-"
proxy | nginx.1 | 2022/08/16 17:33:01 [error] 25#25: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myserverIP, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain1.com", referrer: "http://www.domain1.com/"
...
proxy | nginx.1 | myserverIP - - [16/Aug/2022:17:33:46 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://www.domain2.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0" "-"
proxy | nginx.1 | 172.25.0.1 - - [16/Aug/2022:17:33:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0" "-"
proxy | nginx.1 | 2022/08/16 17:33:52 [error] 25#25: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.25.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "domain2.com", referrer: "http://domain2.com/"
```

I don't know if this error is causing the problem, buy I just see on my domains: Welcome to nginx! I can't see my apps running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your problem, but I can give some advices.

1. **Mount of vhostd**
   You have a mount `vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d`. If you have settings in there, then you should share them with us.
   If not, then just remove the mount.
2. **Multidomain pattern**
   You specified multiple domains in a different pattern as `jwilder/nginx-proxy`.
   Instead of `VIRTUAL_HOST=domain1.com www.domain1.com` you should write `VIRTUAL_HOST=domain1.com,www.domain1.com`.
   See [jwilder/nginx-proxy, chapter "Multiple Hosts"](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy)

Comment: Great! I have written a comma like you point out and it works. I don't have settings in vhostd, so I have removed it. Thanks, akop.

Comment: When I write docker-compose up -d and visit my domains, the apps are running. After that, if I don't click tabs the apps appear inactive, I woud say sleeping. I would like to know how to fix this and see the apps always active.

Comment: Docker will not put apps into a "sleep state". I don't know shiny, maybe there a logic like this.

Comment: I think it's nginx. About 1 minute after visiting my domain without clicking tabs, the domain appears idle, like a session timed out, and the screen color changes. I would like to know if there is a way to set this in docker compose, something like NGINX_TIMEOUT=30 minutes.

Comment: nginx is only acting as proxy, it will never change your app. If the screen-color changing, it must be come from shiny.

Comment: I don't use a proxy and I type in the command line this: docker run -d --rm --name myapp1 -p 80:8080 app1_image. So the web app keeps the same appearance all the time as when it is started. When I run the docker compose containers with the nginx proxy, the screen color changes after 1 minute. The screen is the same as when I kill the docker container. That's why I think I have to set something in docker compose.

Comment: To change the color of your site, nginx must inject a script into your site and must detect inactivity (without knowing anything about your app). And that is not the case - nginx is a proxy. What is possible: That shiny open connections and keep them open. Perhaps nginx will close these connections.

Comment: Ok, that could be the reason. There is a sentence in the configuration file: proxy_read_timeout 60. I have tried this: https://wiki.ssdt-ohio.org/display/rtd/Adjusting+nginx-proxy+Timeout+Configuration It works! Great!